# speed up python process (huge data search)

Tags: python, performance, search

```
for data in DBS:
            if any(elem1 in data for elem1 in set_deletelist):
                h.write(data +'\n')
            else:
                pass
```

A script that only writes out URLs that exist in 750,000 rows (set_deletelist) (set type) of a 1,000,000 row (DBS) (set type)takes 10,000 hours to finish processing.
Is there a good way to speed up the process?

I have changed from a list type to a set type, but it seems that further speed-up is needed.
The environment used is ec2 of aws.

Comment: So `data` is a set and `set_deletelist` is a set? Then `if data & set_deletelist:` should be a bit faster.

Comment: A intersect B = B intersect A. Try `any(elem1 in set_deletelist for elem1 in data)`. As it is, you are iterating over a large set in each pass through the loop. It might also help to move the write outside the loop. Accumulate the things to be written into a list. Don't know if that will make much difference since Python might store them in a buffer already.